# Getting error while passing value to sp_xml_preparedocument

Tags: sql-server, xml

DECLARE @xml XML;

```
SET @xml = N'"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><NominalIds><Id>6416</Id><Id>9</Id><Id>6405</Id><Id>6400</Id><Id>6404</Id><Id>6407</Id><Id>0</Id></NominalIds>"';
DECLARE @idoc INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xml
```

error is

> XML parsing: line 1, character 7, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input

Comment: I found some related query to this but none of suggestion worked for me that's why i raised it.

Comment: What's that `"` doing there at the begin and end? Get rid of it. Strings in T-SQL are enclosed only by single quotes.

Comment: It returns XML parsing: line 1, character 15, A string literal was expected. But if i correct xml string by this - '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><NominalIds><Id>6416</Id><Id>9</Id><Id>6405</Id><Id>6400</Id><Id>6404</Id><Id>6407</Id><Id>0</Id></NominalIds>' then it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @xml XML;

SET @xml = N'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><NominalIds><Id>6416</Id><Id>9</Id><Id>6405</Id><Id>6400</Id><Id>6404</Id><Id>6407</Id><Id>0</Id></NominalIds>';
DECLARE @idoc INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xml
```

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated ...

Answer (score 1):

Your xml string is not correct format

Remove double quote at the start and end, remove `\` before `"`

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><NominalIds><Id>6416</Id><Id>9</Id><Id>6405</Id><Id>6400</Id><Id>6404</Id><Id>6407</Id><Id>0</Id></NominalIds>';
DECLARE @idoc INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xml

--- do stuff

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated ...

Comment: thanks @Shnugo, i am using both of `openxml` and `xquery`

Answer (score 0):

You were told already, that the `"` and the `\"` were wrong...

But you should walk a different path anyway...

`FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

For your example this would be the approach:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><NominalIds><Id>6416</Id><Id>9</Id><Id>6405</Id><Id>6400</Id><Id>6404</Id><Id>6407</Id><Id>0</Id></NominalIds>';

SELECT id.value(N'(text())[1]',N'int')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/NominalIds/Id') AS A(id)
```

The result

```
6416
9
6405
6400
6404
6407
0
```